# Document center, record center, and document workspace differences

Tags: 2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a document center and a records center?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21926/whats-the-difference-between-a-document-center-and-a-records-center)

What are the differences between a document center, record center, and document workspace, in 2010? How do I decide to use one over another?

Thanks